# Understanding objects passed in a class and self calling method in Python

Tags: python, function, class, oop, object

Can someone help me understand the Python code below. I am trying to figure what "output = layer.ingredients(input_)" does? I also don't understand how the class handles the object being passed. For example, how would one use the parameter in the contractor?

```
class Lasagna(Layer): 

    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.layers = layers

    def ingredients(self, input_):
        # We remember the inputs for each layer so that we can use them
        self.inputs = []
        for layer in self.layers:
            self.inputs.append(input_)
            output = layer.ingredients(input_)
            input_ = output
        return output 
lasagna = Lasagna([Linear(784, 100), Function1(), Linear(100, 10), Function2()])
```

Thanks

Comment: it calls the `ingredients` method of each `layer` instance , with `_input` as the argument ...

Comment: use `print(input_)` and `print(output)` to see it.